# weakly locally one-to-one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, education, learning

Is there any standard name for this concept that is weaker than local one-to-one-ness?

In some open neighborhood of $x_0$ there is no point $x\ne x_0$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Or, if you like: In some neighborhood of $x_0$, for every point $x$ in that neighborhood, $f(x)=f(x_0)$ only if $x=x_0$.

Might one simply say that "$f$ is weakly locally one-to-one at $x_0$"?

Trivial question, it might seem, if it's only about mathematics.  Maybe it's about psychology of learning mathematics.  I recently came across this error: If $f\;'(a)>0$, the $f$ is strictly increasing in some neighborhood of $a$.  (Much less recently, I made that mistake myself, when, as an undergraduate, I was frustrated by my inability to write what I thought must be a simple $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of that proposition.)  Would people be less likely to make that mistake if somewhere in the recesses of their brain they subconsciously remembered hearing that "If $f\;'\ne 0$ at a point, then $f$ is weakly locally one-to-one at that point."?

Comment: I've completely revised it.  I realized it didn't say what I meant and came back to fix it, expecting a hundred downvotes and 50 indignant comments.  Apparently I got here before they did.

Comment: I was busy trying to figure out why weakly locally 1-1 wasn't equivalent to 1-1. :)

Comment: Your last comment about $f'\ne0$ at a point is interesting, from a pedagogical standpoint (and in and of itself). I think your statement can be proven without MVT. Then you could ask if $f'\ne0$ at a point implies monotonicity near the point. Show that this is false, and then ask "what extra condition would be needed to get monotonicity"?

Comment: To quote my discrete math professor: if you try to prove something and fail, and then find out this something is false then you did a good job not proving a false claim.

Comment: @DavidMitra : Certainly the following can be proved without MVT.  If $f\;'(a)>0$, then in some neighborhood of $a$, for all $x$ in that neighborhood, if $x>a$ then $f(x)>f(a)$ and if $x<a$ then $f(x)<f(a)$.  All you need to do is set $\varepsilon=|f(a)|$, then let $\delta>0$ be so small that for $x$ in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$, the difference quotient $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $f\;'(a)$.  That implies the difference quotient is positive, and the result easily follows.  No MVT needed.

Answer (score 1):

A map between topological spaces is called *discrete* if the preimage of every point is a discrete set, i.e., has no points of accumulation. [In this post all maps are continuous.] This property is weaker than being locally injective. As you observe, every differentiable function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ with nonvanishing derivative is discrete.

The discreteness property usually appears in tandem with *openness* (the image of every open set is open). For example, every discrete and open map between planar domains is the composition of a holomorphic function with a homeomorphism; this is [Stoilov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_map#Properties). In higher dimensions the equation (discrete and open)=(X)$\circ$(homeomorphism) remains unsolved for X. (One would like the elements of class X to satisfy some sort of Cauchy-Riemann equations.)

A fundamental result on discrete and open maps between $n$-dimensional topological manifolds is Chernavskii's theorem: the branch set (=the set of points where the map is not locally injective) has topological dimension $\le n-2$; in particular it does not separate the space.

Comment: "As you observe, every differentiable function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ with nonvanishing derivative is discrete." If "nonvanishing" means _nowhere_ vanishing, then that is not what I said. I wrote of a function whose derivative is nonzero at _one_ point.